# Having trouble with code snippet to write set properties

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have this code snippet to write set properties more faster on a class, but I just don't know why it just doesn't work the tab stop inside the parenthesis. Here is the definition for the snippet;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Set de la clase de Negocio</Title>
      <Author>Jorge Torselli</Author>
      <Description>Establece el set modificado para el campo</Description>
      <Shortcut>set</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Nombre_set</ID>
          <ToolTip>Escribir el nombre del campo en cuestión</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Tipo_dato</ID>
          <ToolTip>Escribir el tipo de dato</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Nueva_asignacion</ID>
          <ToolTip>El tipo de dato y nombre que se le asignara</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>Nombre_campo</ID>
          <ToolTip>EL nombre del campo al que hace referencia = al que se le asigno</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[public void set$Nombre_set$($Tipo_dato$ $Nueva_asignacion$) {this$Nombre_campo$ = $Nueva_asignacion$;}]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

It is on Visual Studio 2015 community, the tab stop it is only working on the first declaration which is Nombre_set, from Nombre_set it jumps to Nombre_campo skipping declaration Tipo_dato, and Nueva_asignacion...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to solve it, I needed some tags and organize the code, here is the edited and functional code ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>set</Title>
      <Shortcut>set</Shortcut>
      <Description>Fragmento de código para set personalizado</Description>
      <Author>Jorge Torselli</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>nombre</ID>
          <Default>nombre</Default>
          <ToolTip>Nombre del set</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>tipo</ID>
          <Default>int</Default>
          <ToolTip>Tipo de variable</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>variable</ID>
          <Default>x</Default>
          <ToolTip>Nombre de variable</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>campo</ID>
          <Default>y</Default>
          <ToolTip>Nombre de campo</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[Public void set$nombre$ ( $tipo$ $variable$ ) { this$campo$ = $variable$; } $end$]]>
    </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

I added the SnippetType tag and placed it inside Expansion; This allows you to insert the snippet where the cursor is placed. This snippet class makes visual studio understand that the snippet will be used to generate type definitions, member definitions and common code constructors.

I added default values ​​in the variables, so you have to replace the default value, that even if you use a snippet with a value that is almost always the same can be added, leaving the option to change it when necessary.

I added $end$ so that the cursor is placed after the code snippet has been expanded.

I also ordered the tag code with indents according to the hierarchy for easier understanding of the code.

This is the link where I found the information I just wrote ...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379562(v=vs.80).aspx